# Install Maven Error - Can you help me?

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

When I install maven to create project or kaptcha are like and find some way not yet fix.

[image]

Can you help me fix this it?

Comment: 1) Don't include a screenshot.  Copy/paste the text direct from the command prompt or redirect it to a file! 2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use maven you need access to the internet, and `repo.maven.apache.org` in particular.  Maven uses this repository to download the latest version of plugins that version supports and the libraries they use.

It appears you have setup a proxy server `http://proxy.hapv.com:8888` and this server is refusing your attempts to access Maven Central. It doesn't appear to be running on that port.  I suggest you check your proxy settings.

You can use maven in an off-line mode once you have working build, but until then you need to let maven install itself from the internet.

Comment: Thank you
I also better understand the problem, thank you enthusiastic help